# Ecobee API client looses authentication randomly

Tags: ecobee-api

I maintain a plugin (driver) for interfacing with the Ecobee servers for the Indigo Home Automation system (https://www.indigodomo.com).  We have many users using the plugin, with no problems.  Except for one...

This particular user is the only one (that I know of), that has two separate instances of the Indigo system, at two different locations, both using the same Ecobee account.  So there's two "clients", both installing the same "app", using the same credentials.  The plugin uses the PIN based authentication method.

He randomly looses authentication at one location or the other.  When that happens, it's usually with an invalid_request return code.  We've been digging into this for a while, and it appears that both installations are getting the same access_token and refresh_token, and then one of them does a token refresh, gets a new refresh_token, and the old token doesn't work at the other location.

So my question is, is multiple instances of the same "app" with the same user account supported?  Or is the server not differentiating between the two and providing the same credentials to both clients?

Answer (score 0):

Having worked with it some myself, as I understand the ecobee API landscape, the authentication and authorization works as follows:

1. An ecobee account can authorize one or more application(s) to access it.
2. Each authorized application is registered to the ecobee account as an OAuth 'client' with a respective 'client_id'.
3. Upon authorization, the application receives its first (expiring) Access Token and a (also expiring) Refresh Token for registration.
4. The authorized application, *regardless of how many instances* of it may be running, shares the same client_id to access the targeted ecobee account for the purposes of interacting with device(s) on said account.

Therefore, while you assert there are two 'clients', I submit they are both sharing the same 'client_id' and are thereby viewed by the ecobee API as the same client.

Even though you are sharing the same 'client_id' from multiple locations, Ecobee applies their restrictions to all requests made, regardless of their location, by the same 'client_id'. See "API Usage Limits" in the [ecobee API documentation](https://developer.ecobee.com/home/developer/api/documentation/v1/operations/get-thermostats.shtml).

Notwithstanding the above, you should be Authorizing your application for the given ecobee account and persisting the same Refresh Token for both locations of your app/plugin.

Each respective location would then subsequently use the same Refresh Token to obtain their own (expiring every 3600 seconds) Access Token. When the Access Token nears expiration or has expired, the Refresh Token is used at each location to obtain a new, expiring Access Token to use for all API requests within the next 3600 seconds (one hour). See [ecobee's documentation on Refreshing Your Tokens](https://developer.ecobee.com/home/developer/api/documentation/v1/auth/token-refresh.shtml).